# how to pipe an R LDA topic model into Topic Model Visualization Engine (TMVE)?

Tags: python, browser, lda, topic-modeling

What's a good framework for building a topic model and topic browser in Python?

```
documents --> topic model --> topic browser
```

[Topic Model Visualization Engine](http://code.google.com/p/tmve/) (TMVE) might pipe the results of Latent Dirichlet Allocation and arrange them into websites.  I have already learned to use topicmodel library in R, but I don't know how to pipe it into TMVE.

---

Mainly, I'm looking for solutions that use Python or R.  I might just try to build my own (really crappy) topic browers from the R output.

It looks like this was a hot research topic a year or two ago. The resources on [David Blei's page](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/topicmodeling.html) seem to be going out of date.

[TMVE](https://github.com/jseabold/tmve) seems to be on gitHub, it was last edited a year ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might also consider the Topical Guide.  Here's an out-of-date web-page:  https://facwiki.cs.byu.edu/nlp/index.php/Topical_Guide
The project is now hosted on GitHub.

Comment: the example looks great and it comes with fun datasets.  i might fork it to work with mongodb